# Let PHP-FPM report the script's current line number on timeout

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, timeout, php7

My website is running successfully on PHP-FPM with NGINX on Debian. Timeout period is set at 300 seconds for NGINX. This is enough for most pages, but some scripts get stuck. I can't reproduce the issue in testing, so I would like to know where the script is stuck. Can PHP-FPM report the last line number when a time out occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable the php-fpm slow log. If a request takes more than a configurable amount of time, php-fpm will dump a stack trace to a log file.

An example configuration, which goes into your php-fpm pool configuration file:

```
slowlog = /var/log/php5/slow.log
request_slowlog_timeout = 5s
```

In this case, any request that takes more than 5 seconds of wall clock time will get a stack dump into `/var/log/php5/slow.log`.

Note that the request *will continue running*.